# Do I need to use cripple studs if header is tight to the top plate?

Tags: framing

So I am placing a 13ft LVL Header beam, in a load bearing wall, to place a Patio Door.

I am using a 3-1/2 by 11-7/8 Versa-Lam LVL beam, as recommended by my Engineer.

I am planning to place the top of the beam tight to the bottom of the plate above, leaving no room for a Cripple stud.

Is this not acceptable? Or do I have to have Cripple Studs between the beam and the top plate?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Your "engineer" certainly has more info than us; follow his/her instructions.

Comment: Will you have to frame in under the beam to get patio door rough opening to correct height?

Comment: @kris, Yes, i have to place one 2 by 4 under the beam to do the rough opening.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Thank you. The engineer actually didn't specify these details. He gave me a stamped diagram, showing what size beam to use.

Comment: Then there is no room for any crippling I assumed you have double jack studs supporting the beam?  The 2x4 goes on the bottom of beam and rests on the jacks

Comment: I am going to use 3-1/2 by 3-1/2 Versa-Lam columns instead of 2 studs (2X4's). Yes there is no space, but I was wondering if cripple studs are required.

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn what's expected of you when an answer is provided.

Comment: @isherwood It looks like the OP has taken the tour; perhaps a link to the [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) article would be in order.

Comment: It was just a reminder to resolve the post. I don't much care to discuss the specific link provided.

Comment: A lot of folks seem to think engineers specify all the details. In my experience working with engineers.... they don’t. I wouldn’t be shocked if those flaming the OP have not worked with an engineer. Often the engineer will spec a beam for the span and that’s that. Obviously a good engineer should/will answer questions.

Answer (score 5):

[image]
No crippling required in cases where there is no room for them

Comment: Are nails/screws needed to connect the top plate to the header?

Comment: @LShaver when framing a wall like this pictured the top of the beam would be attached to the stud wall top 2x6 After walls are stood up and braced off the top plate is installed nailed into top of wall.   A retrofit beam would also need to be attached to the top of the wall. Various methods could be used depending on accessibility to the top of the top plate. Toe nailing up into the stud wall  can work or use screws same way. Or  very long screws down from top of top plate. Or use some Simpson structural hardware to  connect the beam to top of wall